# What are the purposes Nashorn can fullfill in real time, being the part of JAVA 8?

Tags: java, nashorn

Even though I have referred the link [use of nashorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318856/using-nashorn-in-java), but I am looking for a more in-depth answer with some real time scenario that best suits the need of nashorn as a feature of JAVA 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases when I used nashorn:

1) Server-side bots for a site with paid tasks. There was some kind of a generated hash-function, mandatory to execute after every task. I cut it from the html and execute with the same parameters.

2) Application for generating tests. The teacher writes "what this code will return" template on some language (usually C++), writes a JS analog and put ${variable_name} instead of real values. Server generate many typical tests with values in intervals and find answers via nashorn.